# Inserting rows with a predefined identity

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a problem when i insert a row in a table; i get this error:

> "An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Phone' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON"

this is my query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Phone ON;  

Insert into Phone 
select * 
from Phone2
where Phone2.PhoneID=5;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Phone OFF;
```

I just need to change identity to int, how i can do it?

thank

Comment: "*when a column list is used*" seems pretty clear to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify column list in your insert statement

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Phone ON; 

Insert into Phone (key_col, col1, col2) 
select key_id, col1, col2 from Phone2 where Phone2.PhoneID=5 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Phone OFF;
```

You may want to RESEED your ID to a value greater than the one you inserted manually

Comment: I can't beacause i have many columns and i want that i use it with another table

Answer (score 0):

There is an option disable the identity for a column by turning it off and you can change it to int as specified in following [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/)

Comment: i can't make changes on the table , i get an alert to save file text

Comment: check if there is a primary key foreign key relation to the table

Comment: Yes i have a primary key foreign key relation to this, because of that i want to convert Identity to int, and use this query for another table because i have many table with this problem

Comment: So you have to remove the relation temporarily then change again after you change to int

Comment: That's impossible, one table have an many relation (about 30), i need a query "alter table phone" and change from identity to int, but i don't know how can i do it

Comment: i tried to change the identity it is easily changeable in the alert don't you get the option to save all the related files

Comment: there is not a query to change the identity ??